# Using HTTP version but Chrome requests HTTPS for all css and js resources

Tags: html

I am developing a website locally, that I deployed on a local server in my private home network.
Everything was working correctly until few days ago.
When I try to access the website with my browser (chrome): http://192.168.1.200:6002/
It relies on other javascript and CSS resources that are requested with their relative URL. Strangely the **https** version of those resources are requested even-though I am using the **http** version of the website, and it doesn't work because my test server doesn't handle https.

index.html (basically just a simple blank HTML file requesting additional css and js resources.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<base href="/" />
<link href="/ab15341ba9ca9f5c0954-1597370913458.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/6246ca147d1f7e1dfe40-1597370913458.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="/runtime-1597370913458.js"></script>
<script src="/20a5174ec910e2652f85-1597370913458.js"></script>
<script src="/0d1c074d5ee241b0dec3-1597370913458.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am requesting those resources with the following tags:

```
<script src="/0d1c074d5ee241b0dec3-1597370913458.js">
<link href="/ab15341ba9ca9f5c0954-1597370913458.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Using Google inspect, I see that chrome is clearly requesting the **https** version, see:

```
---- General ----
Request URL: https://192.168.1.200:6002/ab15341ba9ca9f5c0954-1597370913458.css
Referrer Policy: no-referrer
---- Request Headers ----
Provisional headers are shown
DNT: 1
Referer
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36
```

Any idea of what is this issue could be?

EDIT, this is what the network tab + console looks like:

[image]

Comment: Are there any redirects in the network tab? Are any of the requests returning code 302, for example?

Comment: @ErikLumme See the picture I appended to my post with the network tab. There is no 302 code.

Comment: Do you use a chrome extension that forces https by any chance?

Comment: No (I only have 2-3 extensions) and I also tried with Firefox and the same happen... it really don't understand. The strange thing is that it was working for years until few days ago and I haven't done any change since then.

Comment: If you have the possibility to test, does the same happen when accessing through `localhost:6002` on the host machine?

Comment: I think I found the issue. I had my version of helmet npm package set to "latest" and few days ago, version 4.0.0 got released. I can now see the header `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains` set by default on any response from my server. This is most likely the cause of this "suddent" change.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. While we don't delete Content-Security-Policy from index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```