# How to force HTML to requesting local resource (css/js) file over HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, express

I just created my own HTML page inside expressJS, everything looks good while running on `localhost` but when I upload it to my server, the HTML requesting all my local `css` or `js` file over HTTPS automatically. How do I force HTML to requesting all my local `css` or `js` using HTTP protocol?

I've tried to find any possible keyword and found my issue is similar to this [Using HTTP version but Chrome requests HTTPS for all css and js resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63435196/using-http-version-but-chrome-requests-https-for-all-css-and-js-resources) but the question is not answered yet

---

#### HTML rendered from local development (`localhost`)

[image]

#### HTML rendered from server

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "local" here? Surely you uploaded your Express code **and** your CSS and JavaScript files to the server.

Comment: Modern browsers will object to mixed protocols. Firefox will block HTTP requests in the middle of an HTTPS page. I'm curious why you think you need to do this.

Comment: but a page loaded using HTTP (which seems to be the case in the question) can still access HTTPS resources @TangentiallyPerpendicular

Comment: @Pointy I don't know how to defined `local` like what i mean, so for example, I've a folder like this `form/index.html`, `form/index.js` and `form/index.css`, but the `index.html` requesting `index.js` and `index.css` over HTTPS protocol when I open it on my server

Comment: You can try few samples here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https

Comment: @flix well if your main pages load with HTTPS, why would you not want the auxiliary content to load with HTTPS also? What goes wrong, in other words?

Comment: The thing is, here in 2024, with *rare* exceptions everything should be HTTPS. It really doesn't make sense not to do that.

Comment: @Pointy that's why I'm confused, I'm requesting over HTTP protocol, but the page requesting resource using HTTPS, http://158.178.229.205:3000/upload/index is my HTML that i created

Comment: I don't think the error is that it's HTTPS so much as some kind of server configuration problem. The browser will use the method of the main page when loading resources from the origin host. If you explicitly force it not to, that'll cause different errors. You need to figure out why your hosting service is freaking out like that.